# RX Packets sent from dummy Linux network device driver are dropped

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am having two (may be related) issues but I will describe the one mentioned in title first.

I am modifying the [dummy network device driver](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.4/source/drivers/net/dummy.c) to echo back the transmitted UDP packet to the transmitting interface. In the callback function of `ndo_start_xmit`, I have added following piece of code to echo back the transmitted packet:

```
struct sk_buff *skb2;
unsigned char *ptr;
skb2 = netdev_alloc_skb(dev, pkt_len + 2);
if(skb2)
{
  ptr = skb_put(skb2 , pkt_len);
  memcpy(ptr , (void*)skb->data, pkt_len);
  /* Code to swap source and destination IP & Ports and increment tx rx counts here */
  netif_rx(skb2);
}
```

Now if I assign IP to interface after inserting this module, send packets on this interface and then run `ifconfig dummy0`, I get following output:

```
dummy0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 42:cd:19:7d:52:3f
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::40cd:19ff:fe7d:523f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING NOARP  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:4 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:192 (192.0 B)  TX bytes:258 (258.0 B)
```

Here we can see that along with packet TX and RX count, RX Drop count is also increasing. Can someone point to the reason why packets are being dropped?

Now coming to the second issue, if I try to run `tcpdump` to capture the packets, as soon as some packet arrives on RX of this `dummy0` interface the whole virtual machine hangs (I guess the kernel panics). Is there something that I am missing in the code which causes this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve both issues by adding:

```
skb2->protocol = eth_type_trans(skb2, dev);
```

just before `netif_rx(skb2)`.